# How to print characters at specfic indices?

Tags: python

I've created a function that lets a user enter a string and an int, splits the string into separate characters and then uses the int value to display the character at that index.

```
def list_character(string, index_list):

    res = []
    res[:] = string

    for i in res:
        print(res[index_list])

list_character("ABCDEF", 0)
```

Result:

```
A
```

However, I am required to display multiple indexes using a list as an argument not just a single one, for example:

```
string = "ABCDEF"
index_list = [0, 0, 1, 5]
```

then the result based on those indexes should be the following:

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'F']
```

Comment: `[string[index] for index in index_list]`

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension

```
def list_character(string, index_list):
  
    return [string[i] for i in index_list]
print(list_character("ABCDEF", [0,0,1,5]))

['A', 'A', 'B', 'F']
```

Comment: ah okay thankyou. Might I also ask, how would I do it so that if an index thats out of bounds is included it igores it?

Comment: @connorling Just check this out. I mean it seems like some homework, please at least try how it works when someone gives you a solution.

Comment: yep fair point. It should be fairly simple to ignore the index out of bounds. Just needs an if check. @connorling try it out and let us know if it doesn't work out. then we can solve where you're stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
def list_character(string, index_list):
 return_list = []
 for i in index_list:
  return_list.append(string[i])
 return return_list
```